# Make a grid of 5*5km on a raster layer map in R?

Tags: qgis, raster, r

I'm trying to make a grid of 5 by 5km on my raster layer map but not sure how to do this. I have read my shapefile in R and rasterized it and have an resolution  of 10 by 10 meter. And I have plants distribution coordinates on this raster map. Now I want to make a grid of 5 by 5 km to calculate the number of plants in each grid.

But stuck with how to make a grid on this raster layer.

---

I followed the suggested procedures but i managed to plot this new raster separately and could only plot the plant distribution coordinates on my base raster map and I could not overlay this new layer with 5 by 5km on top to extract or find out the plants distribution per area. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.
below is what i did:

```
landuse <- readShapeSpatial("~/Documents/vegetation_analysis/PNPP.shp", 
                        proj4string = CRS("+proj=utm + datum=WGS84"))

p <- raster(extent(landuse)) #creats a raster with the extent of VEG in area PNPP
projection(p) <- proj4string(landuse) #uses the projection of the shapefile
res(p) <- 100.0 #sets the resolution of the raster 

p1 <- rasterize(landuse, field="TYPES", r) #converts BHT to a raster
plot(p1) ##plot this one

#loaded my vegetation locations
veg_d <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = cbind(VD$long, VD$lat),
                               data = VD,
                               proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
)

veg_d <- spTransform (veg_d, CRS("+init=epsg:4240"))

#make a new occurance layer as suggested here
t <- raster(xmn=0, ymn=0, xmx=100000, ymx=100000, resolution=10,
            crs='+proj=utm +ellps=WGS84')
t <- setValues(t, sample(x=0:1, size=ncell(t), replace=T))
plot(t)

##then raster aggregation with aggregate
t_agg <- aggregate(x=t, fact=400, fun=sum)
t_agg
plot(t_agg)
points(veg_g,col="blue") ##does not make the points on the plot????
```

I also plotted:

```
plot(landuse)
points(veg_g, col="blue")
plot(t_agg, add=TRUE)  ##
```

but i don't plot the raster over this and i am not able to get it.

I am new to R.

Comment: I'm interested in `p1` raster... Wich information contains? You can use it into `aggregate()` function, but first I think you need to filter land use data

Comment: the p1 raster contains 15 types of vegetation types. and another thing is i am also spending 2 hours each time to import the shape file first and then to conver to raster. So is there also a method to keep this raster permanently so that i don't have to keep on importing the shape file first?

Comment: Use `writeRaster()` to save it in your machine. Also, rasterization is pretty much faster in QGIS, you can create a empy raster in R, save it in a folder and use QGIS to rasterize vector file using this template, it's the fastest approach. I update my answer

Comment: thank you so much @aldo_tapia for this shortcut it will save me 2 hours for getting files everyday

Answer (score 7):

Just aggregate raster layer.

1) Occurrence layer:

```r
library(raster)

r <- raster(xmn= 0, ymn= 0, xmx = 100000,ymx = 100000, resolution = 10,
            crs = '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ')

r <- setValues(r, sample(x = 0:1, size = ncell(r), replace = T))

plot(r)
```

[image]

2) Raster aggregation with `aggregate`. Function documentation:

> **x**     Raster* object or SpatialPolygons* object
>
> **fact**    integer. Aggregation factor expressed as number of cells in each direction (horizontally and vertically). Or two integers
>   (horizontal and vertical aggregation factor) or three integers (when
>   also aggregating over layers). See Details
>
> **fun**   function used to aggregate values

Code:

```r
r_agg <- aggregate(x = r, fact = 500, fun = sum)

r_agg
## class       : RasterLayer 
## dimensions  : 30, 20, 600  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
## resolution  : 5000, 5000  (x, y)
## extent      : 0, 1e+05, 0, 150000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 
## data source : in memory
## names       : layer 
## values      : 124213, 125983  (min, max)

plot(r_agg)
```

[image]

---

Example with categorial raster.... I should remark **this is a reproducible example**, so you need to adapt this code, not paste it immediately after the last part of your code.

Suppose a 13-class categorical raster:

```r
library(raster)

r <- raster(xmn= 0, ymn= 0, xmx = 100000,ymx = 100000, resolution = 10,
            crs = '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ')

r <- setValues(r, sample(x = 1:13, size = ncell(r), replace = T))
r <- as.factor(r)
levels(r) <- list('landcover' = data.frame(ID = 1:13, Class = paste0('class_',1:13)))

rasterVis::levelplot(r)
```

[image]

Select aim class and aggregate it:

```r
# Occurrence of Class 10, for example

r_class10 <- mask(r, r == 10, maskvalue = 0)
r_class10[r_class10 == 10] <- 1 # to obtain only values NA and 1, easy to sum
r_agg <- aggregate(x = r_class10, fact = 500, fun = sum, na.rm = T)
rasterVis::levelplot(r_agg)
```

[image]

Pixel value is occurrence number in a 5x5 km window.

---

## Procedure for point layer

---

```r
# packages used in this example
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(latticeExtra)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(321) # make this example fully reproducible

# first, create grid. You need to define bounds and CRS... This is only an example, could be a rasterization of your point's bbox
r <- raster(xmn= 0, ymn= 0, xmx = 100000,ymx = 100000, resolution = 5000,
            crs = '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ')

# set values for each pixel
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))

# convert to SPDF
grid <- as(r,'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame')

# change field name and plot
names(grid@data) <- 'ID'
spplot(grid, zcol = 'ID')+layer(sp.text(coordinates(gCentroid(grid, byid = T)), txt = grid@data$ID, cex = 0.5))
```

[image]

```r
# With this, I create a layer representing species occurrence position, ONLY FOR EXAMPLE PURPOSE
veg1 <- spsample(grid, 500, type = 'random')
veg2 <- spsample(grid, 500, type = 'clustered')
veg <- veg1 + veg2
veg <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(veg, data.frame(FID = 1:length(veg),
                                              Class = sample(x = paste0('Class_',1:13),
                                                             size = length(veg), replace = T)))
spplot(veg, zcol = 'Class') # plot with observations distribution with all classes
```

[image]

```r
# here, I select only one classs... Can be either with all or some of they
veg_10 <- veg[veg@data$Class == 'Class_10',]

# intersect layer
veg_10inter <- intersect(veg_10, grid)

# result.. I don't know why the ID field of grid change to 'd'
veg_10inter
## class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
## features    : 70 
## extent      : 12.32643, 96434.61, 257.5466, 97562.83  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 
## variables   : 3
## names       :  FID,    Class,   d 
## min values  :    3, Class_10,  16 
## max values  : 1005, Class_10, 397 

# sumamrize data
df <- veg_10inter@data %>% group_by(d) %>% arrange(d) %>% summarise(n = n())

# create a new field in grid vector
grid@data$N_class_10 <- NA

# place number of occurrences
grid@data[grid@data$ID %in% df$d,'N_class_10'] <- df$n

# plot results! clustered zone has sense here
spplot(grid, zcol = 'N_class_10')
```

[image]

You can save this layer with `writeOGR()` function of `rgdal` package.

Comment: You could also just make a copy of an empty raster and then change the resolution. Following your example:  r500 <- r; res(r) <- c(500,500)

Comment: @JeffreyEvans yes. But how to count occurrences by new pixel resolution?

Comment: That is why I added this as a comment. For just changing resolution this is a quick solution that does not require aggregation. For what the OP wants where plants are counted, the use of raster::aggregate is the most efficient approach. There are however, other reasons that one would want to change cell size.

Comment: Thank you @aldo_tapia and ....i will try the next recommended by

Comment: @Johnny I made an edit more to the post. Check it, now the procedure is correct and calculation a little faster

Comment: Now i am wondering how i can calculate the grids that has the plants with coordinates. I plotted the endemic plant with distribution coordinates over this map i created similar to r_agg. Could you please help how to extract the grids with plant coordinates? @aldo_tapia

Comment: What did you mean with extract grids? a vector file like a fish-net? And for plant coordinates.... Original vector file is point type? If it, you can intersect vector file with polygonized grid raster, using a grid with ID values instead sum of occurrences to identify which plant is inside each grid

Comment: original file for the plants distribution is coordinates along with plant names and associated climatic information. so now on the land use raster with 5 by5 km i made, i plotted the plants with the coordinates but unable to get which grids are having how many plants in each grid..........@aldo_tapia

Comment: my main question from this r is to calculate the number of plants in each grid of 5 by 5km and identify which are these grids

Comment: @Johnny I thought vector file was land use product from Sentinel-2 (10 x 10 m). The procedure is easiest. I’ll update the answer in a hour

Comment: @aldo_tapia thank you so much for being so helpful. being new to R its been so difficult for me and also new to qgis and even worst doing gis is in R. this forum is great for learning and sharing. i love it.

Comment: @Johnny ready. Couldn't be more complete now

Comment: @aldo_tapia thanks a million finally figured it out ....took a while to understand though

Comment: @Johnny you welcome. If this solve your issue, please accept the answer